# pipenv dependencies OK in terminal, not in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pipenv

Using only the terminal, I got my project installed using an existing Pipfile, and pipenv install, etc.  I can run it in the terminal and all dependencies are met.

I created a PyCharm project using the directory. In the project settings, I have the pipenv intepreter created by the virtual environment chosen in the project settings, but none of the packages that are installed and working are shown in that window, see project interpreter image

[image]

When I try to run the program in PyCharm it wants to install all the dependencies in the Pipfile.  Does it have to go through this "Install" (or "reinstall") process in order to get the paths right, or is there something else I'm missing?

Or is this because I didn't use Pipfile.lock explicitly when I installed things in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

After playing for a week with PyCharm, it seems you **do** have to allow PyCharm to make its own pipenv environment or install from Pipfile.lock, although it uses the packages you've already downloaded.